# Pandas Data Rolling on Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, rolling-computation

The data I have has 7 columns (Date, Country, Channel, Platform, Category, Purchase, Sell). The columns Country and Channel are rolled up at All level.

The data looks like this:

| Date | Country | Channel | Category | Platform | Purchase | Sell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-25 | All | All | App | Cell | 14 | 14 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | All | App | Laptop | 10209 | 20745 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | All | Web | Cell | 1132 | 18128 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | All | Web | Laptop | 16086 | 75491 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | All | Free | Cell | 96 | 547 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | All | Free | Laptop | 4281 | 16231 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | All | App | Cell | 0 | 2 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | All | App | Laptop | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | All | Web | Cell | 362 | 392 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | All | Web | Laptop | 412 | 379 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | All | Free | Cell | 0 | 658 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | All | Free | Laptop | 921 | 417 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | All | App | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | All | App | Laptop | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | All | Web | Cell | 346 | 550 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | All | Web | Laptop | 601 | 458 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | All | Free | Cell | 0 | 1001 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | All | Free | Laptop | 1197 | 593 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | Direct | App | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | Direct | App | Laptop | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | Direct | Web | Cell | 8 | 10 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | Direct | Web | Laptop | 12 | 14 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | Direct | Free | Cell | 0 | 20 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | Direct | Free | Laptop | 23 | 18 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | Email | App | Cell | 11 | 12 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | Email | App | Laptop | 9 | 10 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | Email | Web | Cell | 56 | 61 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | Email | Web | Laptop | 58 | 59 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | Email | Free | Cell | 12 | 27 |
| 2021-03-25 | All | Email | Free | Laptop | 40 | 17 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | Direct | App | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | Direct | App | Laptop | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | Direct | Web | Cell | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | Direct | Web | Laptop | 10 | 25 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | Direct | Free | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | Direct | Free | Laptop | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Direct | App | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Direct | App | Laptop | 0 | 3 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Direct | Web | Cell | 0 | 6 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Direct | Web | Laptop | 1 | 29 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Direct | Free | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Direct | Free | Laptop | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Email | App | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | Email | App | Laptop | 3 | 5 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | Email | Web | Cell | 1 | 30 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | Email | Web | Laptop | 5 | 23 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | Email | Free | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | US | Email | Free | Laptop | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Email | App | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Email | App | Laptop | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Email | Web | Cell | 1 | 17 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Email | Web | Laptop | 18 | 70 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Email | Free | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-25 | India | Email | Free | Laptop | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | All | App | Cell | 14 | 14 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | All | App | Laptop | 10209 | 20745 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | All | Web | Cell | 1132 | 18128 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | All | Web | Laptop | 16086 | 75491 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | All | Free | Cell | 96 | 547 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | All | Free | Laptop | 4281 | 16231 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | All | App | Cell | 0 | 2 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | All | App | Laptop | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | All | Web | Cell | 362 | 392 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | All | Web | Laptop | 412 | 379 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | All | Free | Cell | 0 | 658 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | All | Free | Laptop | 921 | 417 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | All | App | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | All | App | Laptop | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | All | Web | Cell | 346 | 550 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | All | Web | Laptop | 601 | 458 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | All | Free | Cell | 0 | 1001 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | All | Free | Laptop | 1197 | 593 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | Direct | App | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | Direct | App | Laptop | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | Direct | Web | Cell | 8 | 10 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | Direct | Web | Laptop | 12 | 14 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | Direct | Free | Cell | 0 | 20 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | Direct | Free | Laptop | 23 | 18 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | Email | App | Cell | 11 | 12 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | Email | App | Laptop | 9 | 10 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | Email | Web | Cell | 56 | 61 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | Email | Web | Laptop | 58 | 59 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | Email | Free | Cell | 12 | 27 |
| 2021-03-26 | All | Email | Free | Laptop | 40 | 17 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | Direct | App | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | Direct | App | Laptop | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | Direct | Web | Cell | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | Direct | Web | Laptop | 10 | 25 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | Direct | Free | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | Direct | Free | Laptop | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Direct | App | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Direct | App | Laptop | 0 | 3 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Direct | Web | Cell | 0 | 6 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Direct | Web | Laptop | 1 | 29 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Direct | Free | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Direct | Free | Laptop | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Email | App | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | Email | App | Laptop | 3 | 5 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | Email | Web | Cell | 1 | 30 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | Email | Web | Laptop | 5 | 23 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | Email | Free | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | US | Email | Free | Laptop | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Email | App | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Email | App | Laptop | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Email | Web | Cell | 1 | 17 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Email | Web | Laptop | 18 | 70 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Email | Free | Cell | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-03-26 | India | Email | Free | Laptop | 1 | 3 |

The output I am looking for will be:

| ALL | ALL | ALL | ALL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country |  | Channel | Category |
| Country | Platform | Channel |  |
| Country | Platform |  | Category |
| Country |  | Channel | Category |
|  | Platform | Channel | Category |
| Country | Platform |  |  |
| Country |  | Channel |  |
| Country |  |  | Category |
|  | Platform | Channel |  |
|  | Platform |  | Category |
|  |  | Channel | Category |
| Country |  |  |  |
|  | Platform |  |  |
|  |  | Channel |  |
|  |  |  | Category |

I am trying to figure out how can I aggregate the columns to get the desired output.

Something that I am trying:

```
select_platform_all=all_df[(all_df['Platform'] == "ALL") ]

make_platform_all_category_all = select_platform_all.groupby(['Date','Platform' ]).agg({'Purchase':'sum', 'Sell':'sum',}).reset_index()
                                                                                           
make_platform_all_category_all["Category"]="ALL"
```

#SINGLES:

```
make_category_all = select_cds_not_all.groupby(['Date','Country', 'Channel', 'Platform']).agg({'Purchase': 'sum',  'Sell': 'sum'}).reset_index()    
                                                                                     
make_category_all["Category"]="ALL"
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking your sample data,  you can summarise in your result format combinations of "All" as follows:

```
df = pd.read_html("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001017/pandas-data-rolling-on-multiple-columns")[0]

# get rows or columns that contain "All"
dfa = df.loc[df.eq("All").any(axis=1), [c for c in df.columns if df[c].eq("All").any()]]
# 1`. replace "All" with column name and value with empty string
# 2. drop duplicates
dfa = dfa.assign(**{c:np.where(dfa[c].eq("All"),c,"") for c in dfa.columns}).drop_duplicates()
# rename columns to "ALL"
dfa.columns = ["ALL" for c in dfa.columns]
dfa
```

|  | ALL | ALL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Country | Channel |
| 6 |  | Channel |
| 18 | Country |  |